# Passing a reference to a method in Ruby to another method

Tags: ruby, methods, reference

I have a function which loops through/transvers something, and I want it to recieve a reference to a function which sets the stop creiteria/do something.
For example, in a class:

```
def a(func_stop,i)
   ret = nil # default
   while(i < 0 ) 
      if (func_stop(@lines[i]))
        ret = i
        break
      end
   end
   return ret
end
```

The idea is that I can pass a reference to the function, kinda like PERL'S

```
func1(\&func, $i);
```

I have looked, but failed to find something like this.
Thanks

Comment: `i` does not change inside the loop?

Comment: @lines comes from where ?

Answer (score 4):

Normally it is done with blocks.

```
def a(max, &func_stop)
  puts "Processing #{max} elements"
  max.times.each do |x|
    if func_stop.call(x)
      puts "Stopping"
      break
    else
      puts "Current element: #{x}"
    end
  end
end
```

Then

```
a(10) do |x|
  x > 5
end
# >> Processing 10 elements
# >> Current element: 0
# >> Current element: 1
# >> Current element: 2
# >> Current element: 3
# >> Current element: 4
# >> Current element: 5
# >> Stopping
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
def a(func_stop,i)
   ret = nil # default
   while(i < 0 ) 
      if (func_stop.call(@lines[i]))
        ret = i
        break
      end
   end
   return ret
end

a(method(:your_function), i)
```